# What are some open source blockchain projects?

Tags: altcoin-development

I was trying to build a blockchain to host my cryptocurrency.For that I was searching for some open source blockchain projects and I came across [Best blockchain open source projects](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-blockchain-open-source-projects) which mentioned names like :

1. Eris
2. MultiChain
3. HydraChain
4. OpenChain

I was concerned whether these projects allow you to build your own blockchain or they just let you build something like a Dapp on their blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

The most famous open source Blockchains are [Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) Blockchain and [HyperLedger](https://www.hyperledger.org/) Blockchain.

Comment: Thanks.Bitcoin allows you to make your cryptocurrency on their blockchain. But as I asked, I was willing to know whether these projects allow you to create your own blockchain. I don't think bitcoin allows you to create your own public blockchain ( I am not considering the option of cloning their blockchain and making changes to it) but [MultiChain](http://www.multichain.com/) provides facility of making your own blockchain. But I am not sure about others and that I was concerned about.

Comment: I don't believe @Farghaly meant creating a currency on top of the Bitcoin network, but rather modifying the Bitcoin source code to create your own p2p network and blockchain.  After all, that's the point of open source software in the first place.  For example, say you were too change the source so that it uses a different TCP port number, and then run a few nodes to seed newer nodes.  Even though your new network follows all the same rules, it is now a separate p2p network and therefore a separate blockchain.